# State of process is Launching when using lldb module in python

Tags: lldb

I am learning to use the LLDB.py module in python and am trying to run the following example I found on http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference. I already added lldb.so to PYTHONPATH. Here is the result I got:

> **Creating a target for './a.out'**
>   **a.out**
>   **SBBreakpoint: id = 1, name = 'main', module = a.out, locations = 1**
>   **SBProcess: pid = 0, state = launching, threads = 0, executable = a.out**

It seems like the program doesn't get started, the state of process is always Launching. Is there any configuration problems or any missing codes?

```
import lldb
import os

def disassemble_instructions(insts):
    for i in insts:
        print i

# Set the path to the executable to debug
exe = "./a.out"

# Create a new debugger instance
debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()

# When we step or continue, don't return from the function until the process 
# stops. Otherwise we would have to handle the process events ourselves which, while doable is
#a little tricky.  We do this by setting the async mode to false.
debugger.SetAsync (False)

# Create a target from a file and arch
print "Creating a target for '%s'" % exe

target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch (exe, lldb.LLDB_ARCH_DEFAULT)

if target:
# If the target is valid set a breakpoint at main
main_bp = target.BreakpointCreateByName ("main", target.GetExecutable().GetFilename());

print main_bp

# Launch the process. Since we specified synchronous mode, we won't return
# from this function until we hit the breakpoint at main
process = target.LaunchSimple (["./story.txt"], None, os.getcwd())

# Make sure the launch went ok
if process:
    # Print some simple process info
    state = process.GetState ()
    print process
    if state == lldb.eStateStopped:
        # Get the first thread
        thread = process.GetThreadAtIndex (0)
        if thread:
            # Print some simple thread info
            print thread
            # Get the first frame
            frame = thread.GetFrameAtIndex (0)
            if frame:
                # Print some simple frame info
                print frame
                function = frame.GetFunction()
                # See if we have debug info (a function)
                if function:
                    # We do have a function, print some info for the function
                    print function
                    # Now get all instructions for this function and print them
                    insts = function.GetInstructions(target)
                    disassemble_instructions (insts)
                else:
                    # See if we have a symbol in the symbol table for where we stopped
                    symbol = frame.GetSymbol();
                    if symbol:
                        # We do have a symbol, print some info for the symbol
                        print symbol
}
```

Comment: Your code has a typo - the main_bp line after "if target:" needs to be indented.  But given that causes a Python IndentationError I'm assuming that happened in the course of copy & paste...  Anyway, your code works correctly - with the added tab - for me on macOS with lldb-902.0.72 so I'm surprised it isn't working for you.  What platform and lldb version are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 and lldb-4.0.0

Comment: I'm not very familiar with lldb on Ubuntu, but I know the lldb testsuite runs successfully there - and it uses the Python interface and does things very similar to your script.  So this should work.  First thing I'd check is whether the process really launches & runs.  For instance, have the process you are debugging do something you can verify happened (touch a file for instance).  Don't set your breakpoint, but rather just let the process run to completion.  If you do that then the state in your script should be lldb.eStateExited, and hopefully you will see the evidence that it actually ran.

Comment: Thanks so much Jim. I tried your suggestion and the process didn't even run. I was thinking it might be some dependency problem, so I reinstalled all the dependencies. Though only 2 out of 609 test cases failed when I ran 'cmake chek-lldb', I still faced same problem for this script.